# $C^m (\bar{\Omega}) \subset W^{m,2}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set, $H^{m}(\Omega)=W^{m,2}(\Omega)$ be the Sobolev space of all functions in $L^2(\Omega)$ with weak derivatives of order $\leq m$ also in $L^2(\Omega)$, and $C^{m}(\bar{\Omega})$ be the set of functions in $C^m(\Omega)$ such that all its derivatives of order $\leq m$ admits a continuous extension to $\bar{\Omega}$. Show that $C^{m}(\bar{\Omega}) \subset H^{m}(\Omega)$.

How should I proceed? I must prove that there is $g \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_\Omega f \partial^\alpha_x\varphi = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_\Omega \partial^\alpha_xf\varphi,$$
$\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$.
I know that $\bar{\Omega}$ must be compact, but that guarantees only that if $f \in C^{m}(\bar{\Omega})$, then $f$ is compactly supported in $\bar{\Omega}$, not on $\Omega$, then I can't use integration by parts. Any hints?

Comment: In your integral equation, there's no $g$. You probably wanted to write $g$ instead of $\partial^{\alpha}f$. Let's start with $m = 1$ and $\alpha = (1, 0, ..., 0)$. What do you need to show?

Comment: You wrote $\partial_x^\alpha f$ where I think you meant $g$. The point is that $\varphi$ *is* compactly supported, and so will be $f$ times any derivative of $\varphi$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot $g$. My problem is that I'm not seeing where to use the fact that $f$ has a continuous extension to $\bar{\Omega}$ (I know that there are $C^m$ functions that are not $H^m(\Omega)$).

Comment: Let's say $f \in C(\Omega)$, why should $f \in L^2(\Omega)$? So basically, you need to show two things: a) your classical derivates $\partial^{\alpha}f$ coincide with the weak derivatives of $f$ and b) these classical derivatives are in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Mike, I figured it out! Thanks!